# WebRequest with mutual authentication

Tags: ssl, x509certificate

**Extra information at the end after comments from Crypt32** (thank you Crypt32!)

I have to send data to a server. I need mutual authentication: the server needs to be certain it is me, and I need to be certain that the server really is the server that I trust. This needs to be dons in a windows program.

To identify itself, the server will send me a certificate that is issued by certificate authorities that I trust: a root certificate and an intermediate certificate:

- Root CA-G2.PEM
- Intermediate CA-G2.PEM

To identify me, the organization gave me a certificate and a private key

- Root CA-G3.PEM
- Intermediate CA-G3.PEM
- MyCertificate.CRT (= pem) and MyCertificate.Private.Key (=RSA)

I have imported all root certificates and intermediate certificates into the windows keystore.

To sent the message:

```
const string url = "https://...//Deliver";
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

// Security:
webRequest.AuthenticationLevel=AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequired;
webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

// Should I add my certificate?
X509Certificate myCertificate = new X509Certificate("MyCertificate.CRT");

// Should I add Certificate authorities?
// only the CA-G2 authorities, so my WebRequest can trust the certificate
// that will be sent by the Server?
// or Should I also add the CA-G3 who issued MyCertificate

// and what about MyCertificate.Private.Key, the RSA file?

// Fill the rest of the WebRequest:
webRequest.Method = "Post";
webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
... etc

// do the call and display the result
using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string soapResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
    }
}
```

The WebResponse doesn't indicate any error. The returned data is an empty (non-null) string. Yet:

```
response.StatusCode == NoContent (204)
soapResult == String.Empty
response.IsMutuallyAuthenticated == false
```

The NoContent and the empty data result are expected. Does the false IsMutuallyAuthenticated indicate that something is wrong with my authentication?

**Added information**

Crypt32 suggested I should convert MyCertificate.CRT and MyCertificate.Private.Key into one PFX (or P12) file.

For this I use openssl.

I concatenated the CA-G3 files into one TrustG3.Pem and created the P12 file:

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -name "<some friendly name>"
                   -certfile TrustG3.Pem
                   -in MyCertificate.CRT
                   -inkey MyCertificate.Private.Key
                   -out MyCertificate.P12
```

After providing a password a proper Pkcs12 file (PFX) was created. The source code changes slightly:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

// Security:
webRequest.AuthenticationLevel=AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequired;
webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var p12Certificate = new X509Certificate("MyCertificate.P12", "my password");
webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(p12Certificate);
```

Alas, this didn't help. The webResponse still says:

```
response.IsMutuallyAuthenticated == false
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does the false IsMutuallyAuthenticated indicate that something is wrong with my authentication?

yes, it does. Because you add only public part of client certificate. There is no associated private key specified. Either, use certificate from certificate store (assuming, cert store contains private key) or import certificate from PFX.

**Update:**

now your client authentication code looks correct. Next step is to check if your client certificate is trusted by server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you suggested but still not authenticated. I've edited the question